# React Native - Calling Flatlist item outside the Flatlist itself

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to have a **Send Order Button** below my **FLATLIST** where this **Send Order Button** will send the states to the other screen/view together with the **item** in my **Flatlist**.

"But the problem is I don't know how to call the **Flatlist**'s item outside the Flatlist itself."

Here's my code

```
export default class Settlement extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
        this.state = {
            ......
    }
    fetchData = async () => {
        ....
        this.setState({ data: json })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                    <Text>Table No: { this.state.tbl }</Text>
                    <Text>{ this.state.DineIn }{ this.state.TakeOut }</Text>
                <FlatList
                data = {this.state.data}
                renderItem = {({ item }) =>
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <Text>{ item.item.order_id }</Text>
                            <Text>Name: { item.menu_name }</Text>     //Flatlist_Items
                            <Text>Price: ₱{ item.menu_price }</Text>
                            <Text>Discount: { item.order_discount }</Text>
                            <Text>Amount: ₱{ item.order_amount }</Text>
                            .....
                            <Text>{ item.spcl_req }</Text>
                            <Text>{ item.order_quantity }</Text>
                            .....
                        </View>
                    </View>
                }/>


                </View>
                        <Text>Number of Orders: { this.state.numOrder }</Text>
                        <Text>Total Amount: ₱{ this.state.TotalSum }</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress = { () => this.props.navigation.navigate('FinalSettlement', {
                            orderID     : item.order_id,
                            Name        : item.menu_name,
                            Price       : item.menu_price,     //Trying to pass
                            Ord_QTY     : item.order_quantity, // the items to other view
                            spcl_req    : item.spcl_req,
                            Discount    : item.order_discount,
                            Amount      : item.order_amount,
                            tbl         : this.state.tbl,
                            pax         : this.state.pax,
                            DineIn      : this.state.DineIn,
                            TakeOut     : this.state.TakeOut,
                            numOrder    : this.state.numOrder,
                            TotalSum    : this.state.TotalSum,
                            userName    : this.state.userName

                        })}>
                        <Text>SEND ORDER</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [RN doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist), list item should be separate component as mentioned in doc

```js
 _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <MyListItem
      id={item.id}
      onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
      selected={!!this.state.selected.get(item.id)}
      title={item.title}
    />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.data}
        extraData={this.state}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
```

And instead of passing a lot of param in navigation function you can use global statement, for example [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

In your case you can get params in your screen 'FinalSettlement' by getParam function from [ReactNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)